# Comparing string elements in list<string> and vector<string>

Tags: c++, regex, string

I would like to compare string elements in `list<string>` and `vector<string>`.

Such code works fine:

```
list<string> FileNamesPatternsList; // In this list there are about 100 files
vector<string> FilesToBeSearched;   // In this vector there are about 300 files

list<string>::iterator compareIterator;
vector<string>::iterator compareIterator2;

for( compareIterator = FileNamesPatternsList.begin(); compareIterator != FileNamesPatternsList.end(); compareIterator++){
for( compareIterator2 = FilesToBeSearched.begin(); compareIterator2 != FilesToBeSearched.end(); compareIterator2++)
            {
                smatch result;
                if(regex_search(*compareIterator2,result,regex(*compareIterator))){
                MyFilewithResults << "File: " << result[0] << "fit to" << *compareIterator2 << endl;
                }
            }

    }
```

Although as result only matched elements are stored to txt file (MyFilewithResults).

How can I store not matched result? Added `if()...else` doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Are the patterns lists actual regular expressions, or are they simply two containers of strings and you're trying to compute a differential?

Comment: You need to have a variable to tell you if you found a match inside the inner loop. Then outside that loop record the result if no match was found.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Both containers are just strings, I'm trying to compare them using regex_search ( successful comparation works fine, but I would like to catch also those files which were not matched). List container is to use sort() and unique() functions

Comment: I know they're strings, but are the strings in `FileNamePatternsList` actual regular expressions (patterns, captures, etc) or are they simply strings? If its just string vs string you're using a sledge hammer to swat flies. Perhaps sort (or maintain as-sorted) the sequences and use [`std::set_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) instead.

Comment: FileNamePatternsList is list of regex e.g. uniqufile.bin when vector is e.g. 01_uniquefile.bin, second_uniquefile.bin. and uniquefile.gz. I need to find all strings which fit to pattern (this works) but also those which don't( its my question here for help )

Comment: there can be a workaround: store to new vector succeffuly matched regex_search results ( patterns), and then compare them with patterns by std::set_difference . But maybe there is another solution?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the solution is to "remember" if you found a match.

So, in pseudo-code:

```
for(every element)
{
  found = false
  for(each thing to match with)
  {
    if (is a match)
    {
       found = true;
       ... do other stuff here ... 
    }
  }
  if (!found)
  {
     ... do whatever you do if it wasn't in the list ...
  }
}
```